# Restoring the environment by sigsetjmp and longsetjmp

Tags: c++, context-switch

I'm using the couple sigsetjmp and singlongjmp with SIGALARM for interrupting a system call, which is illustrated in the following code

```
//data of Alarm_interrupter
void (TClass::*fpt)(const char*);   // pointer to member function
TClass* pt2Object;                  // pointer to object
===================================================
//for timeout processing
static sigjmp_buf jmpbuf;
static void recvfrom_alarm(int) {
    siglongjmp(jmpbuf, 1);
}
======================================================
void Alarm_interrupter::start_timeout() {
    signal(SIGALRM, recvfrom_alarm);
    alarm(timeout);
    (*pt2Object.*fpt)("timeouted before sigsetjmp"); //this call works OK
    if (sigsetjmp(jmpbuf,1) != 0) {
        //at this point, pt2Object is still OK,
        //but fpt seems to point to nothign.
        (*pt2Object.*fpt)("timeouted after sigsetjmp");
    }
    return;
}
==============================================================
```

Before sigsetjmp returnn 1, the call using object and the method pointer: *pt2Object.*fpt("timeouted before sigsetjmp") is OK, but after sigsetjmp return 1, this call failed. 
After examining the state of variables, I noticed that the object pointer "pt2Object" is still Ok, but the method pointer "fpt" seems to different.

I think that one possible reasons for this is that sigsetjmp cannot restore the whole earlier environment, which includes the method pointer "fpt".

Could you guys help me fix this problem. Thanks so much!

Comment: Please Please **DO NOT USE** `setjmp` etc. Nor make signal handlers complicated. There are better mechanisms. Please advise what is desired.

Comment: These functions do not restore values of static/global variables.

Comment: @EdHeal: Actually almost all of the "better mechanisms" have unsolvable race conditions. If you really want to use `alarm` to reliably interrupt an operation (and this is only legal if the operation to be interrupted is async-signal-safe), some form of `longjmp` is your only option.

Comment: @R. I disagree. Signals are not controlled. Keep signal handlers simpler. Put a mark on the blackboard and then the process can periodically check if that mark exists. At least the process will know where ir is in its train of thought.

Comment: @EdHeal That doesn't work if you can't trust that the process doesn't contain an unintentional endless loop. What processes are legitimately optimized such that they can't check a flag, and so complex that such a loop can't practically be guarded against, is another question. Probably the OP isn't in such a situation, but the general assumption is that it can arise.

Comment: The point of `alarm` is usually to interrupt an operation that otherwise might block indefinitely. The other signal handling idioms cannot solve this problem without race conditions. The naive approach would be to set the signal handler as interrupting (non-restart) and also set a "cancel" flag from the signal handler, and then do something like `if (cancel_flag || (blocking_op(...)<0 && errno==EINTR)) { /* handle timeout case */ }`, but this has a race condition you can't fix.

Comment: @n.m: two data member of  Alarm_interrupter is: "fpt" and "pt2Object". What is different between two variable? Why pt2object is still OK but fpt is not validated anymore??

Comment: @Potatoswatter - Why so many double negatives - your argument does not make any sense.

Comment: R. Where is the race conditions? Why interrupt a process and leave a file/socket in an unknown state?

Comment: @EdHeal Reducing negatives: Checking a flag works only if you can guarantee all loops between flag-checks terminate. You can work around that by adding flag checks to more loops, but at some point performance suffers. The OP is probably not in such a situation, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: An if statement once in a while is not so difficult. Or a corrupted file, dodgy data sent across the network. Part of the stuff on the heap lost forever and a memory leak....

Comment: @EdHeal It makes more sense for graph analysis, where the structure might be fixed or cleaned up by another process later, and might embed tricky structures, than for I/O or structure generation tasks.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - Eh? Please explain

Comment: Longjmp restores registers saved by setjmp. Setjmp does not save any objects. All objects stay the same as they where at the time of longjmp, except local variables that were changed between setjmp and longjmp ― those are indeterminate.

Comment: @EdHeal You say this practice could cause file or network corruption or memory leaks. The solution is not to do this on a thread doing those things. Isolate the difficult-to-abort stuff onto one thread, interrupt that, and let another thread clean it up.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - But the other thread doing the "difficult to abort" stuff needs to recognise that it needs to abort - back to the original problem. Just have a variable (boolean) set to true when the thing needs to end.

Answer (score 1):

As Potatoswatter points out, using the alarm to delay the `longjmp` is too clever to rely upon. You have to call 'sigsetjmp' first. It has to happen *before* you try to return there.

The only way `sigsetjmp` or `setjmp` will work is following this pseudocode.

```
if (sigsetjmp(...) != 0) {
    //  Error handling code
}
// code that might call siglongjmp to bail out to Error handling code
```

You see, it has to be executed once to perform the save of the context. This initializes the `jmpbuf`. If you call `longjmp` without having called `setjmp` earlier in the execution, the behavior cannot be predicted.

Also, `longjmp` will tend to obliterate any local variables you might try to use.

```
int var = 3;
var = 2;
if (sigsetjmp(...) != 0) {
    //  Error handling code
    printf("%d", var); // could print 2, 3 or even "potato". Local vars get trashed.
}
// code that might call siglongjmp to bail out to Error handling code
```

So you really want to do everything interesting *after* the `*setjmp`.

```
int var = 3;
if (sigsetjmp(...) != 0) {
    //  Error handling code
    var = 2;
    printf("%d", var); // now you know it's 2
}
// code that might call siglongjmp to bail out to Error handling code
```

For any hope of it surviving across the `*longjmp`, it needs to be marked `volatile`.

```
volatile int var = 3;
var = 2;
if (sigsetjmp(...) != 0) {
    //  Error handling code
    printf("%d", var); // probably 2
}
// code that might call siglongjmp to bail out to Error handling code
```

And even this may not be enough. It may need to be something called a sigatomic_t or something similar. But try not to need crazy stuff like that.

```
int var = 3;
memcpy(var, (int *){2}); //memcpy is pretty reliable (C99ism: immediate pointer))
if (sigsetjmp(...) != 0) {
    //  Error handling code
    printf("%d", var); // probably 2
}
// code that might call siglongjmp to bail out to Error handling code
```

Comment: Yes I do call sigsetjmp before calling siglongjmp. After timeout, the call siglongjmp is call, it would trigger sigsetjmp return 1, and my error code is call. But the call "(*pt2Object.*fpt)("timeouted after sigsetjmp");" doesn't work anymore. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: No you don't. As soon as the signal handler is set, `siglongjmp` is potentially callable, but you have not yet called `sigsetjmp`.

Comment: He means the second call, inside the "handler". @khanhhh89 You're deviating from the pseudocode I've shown. It has to follow this form.

Comment: @khanhhh89 What R is talking about is the fact that you're relying on the alarm timeout to delay the signal handler. It would be better not to set the alarm at all until after `sigsetjmp`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Yes. Good way to put it.

Comment: #Potatiswatter, @R: This is my use code:                                       1. Alarm_interrupter<mobile_service> timer(this,&mobile_service::handle_timeout,15); //initialize timer with error handler and timeout
3. timer.start_timeout(); //start counting
4. transport_ptr_->open(); //the system call that could be blocked; therefore, needing interrupted by alarm signal

Comment: Ok. You still need to have `setjmp` and all the error handling block *before* you set the timer. It's the reverse of a try/catch block. `*longjmp` is always a jump *back* to a previous point of *execution* set by `*setjmp`.

Comment: It means that when timeout is expired, it will trigger funtion "recvfrom_alarm", which then call "siglongjmp". this siglongjmp would restore the enviroment, which is saved by sigsetjmp ealier. Unfortunately, when sigsetjmp returned 1, the variable "fpt"(the method pointer) is invalidated anymore??

Comment: @luser droog: Got it, but it still doesn't solve my problem. Why the variable "fpt" is not invalidated when "sigssetjmp"??

Comment: Oh. I see. That's the other snag of `longjmp` you can't rely on the values of any variables that may be modified but not *saved*. Try marking the variable `volatile`. Even that may not work. You may have to recalculate, or make sure it's written to memory with something like `memcpy` that's more likely to be atomic. An optimizer may delay storing variables in memory so it can keep them in registers for speed. But `longjmp` isn't smart enough to sort this out. Or do all this before you set the variable at all.

Comment: @luser droog: Thanks so much ^^. In addition to using "SIGALRM, sigsetjmp, siglongjmp", could you give some some other solution for interrupting system call such as recv, send...

Comment: Not really. I just know *setjmp/*longjmp is very fragile. And you have to use just the right way or all bets are off.